# Cant figure out, why i get a 403

Tags: youtube-data-api

i try to setup the youtube api but i get a 403.

I tried to setup several times- without success.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,contentDetails&id=-DIJvggBrg8&key=xyz

Maybe someone is able to help me or even login to the console for a setup?

Comment: Please note that the API key is a user's private information. Therefore nobody should include it in API url's himself/herself makes public! In such cases, as yours is, that key must be quickly deleted from Google's developers console, https://console.developers.google.com/. Upon that, just ask the Web UI to get you a new key.

Comment: Unfortunately, the description you provided does not include important context information. The *FORBIDDEN (403)* error has attached error codes: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/core_errors#FORBIDDEN. That extra information may lead to solving your problem. Consequently, please post the entire JSON text received from the enpoint you've queried.

Comment: Hello Stvar, thanks for your input. I have edited the post. I was forwarded to this forum by gsc support. Unfortunately iam no coder and iam really lost here. Maybe can you help me with that directly in the console? Of course, i can pay for your help.

Comment: @Dennis: Unfortunately I think your expectations here are incorrect. Stack Overflow is not a forum and it's not a place to hire developers or even to get free tutoring. Stack Overflow is a collaborative encyclopedia of answers to questions about programming. As such, it's not clear to me what kind of answer you're looking for in response to your question.

Comment: @Dennis: You don't have to be a coder (programmer for that matter) to create/delete API keys from Google's console. See for example this video [YouTube API Key for WordPress Plugin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4uqJRUPWLs4) -- which I found upon a simple *google* search.

Comment: Thans for your inputs, but i made this steps already x times and therefore i get these 403- also with unrestricted access. Any idea where this 403 comes from even i setup as in the video?

Answer (score 0):

The 403 error by itself is not of immediate use. Its attached error code (as I already pointed out [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55725403/cant-figure-out-why-i-get-a-403#comment98135892_55725403)) sheds light on the things that happened.

The API responds to any query you make with a text (that is structured in JSON format). That response text contains the needed error code.

I suggest you to proceed with the following steps:

1. delete the old API key (right now it is still accessible!);
2. create a new API key and
3. run your API query using the new key and then post here the API response text.

Note that I checked the video [-DIJvggBrg8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DIJvggBrg8) to which your query refers to with my own API key and got no error but a JSON text describing the video.

Comment: I created the credentials several times, but i saw here the quota is set to 0 for whatever reason. https://www.screencast.com/t/3vqWjaRuGWe

Is that the reason i get a 403?

Comment: PS: I created a whole new project and now everything works :-) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good. But for some reason, your old key still seems to be accessible: issuing your initial query above, I got a 403 error with the attached message ``Project ... has been scheduled for deletion and cannot be used for API calls...``. Private keys should be private, otherwise someone with malicious intentions could abuse the API in your name.