# Im getting "Access Not Configured" error when retrieving video. Working fine previously

Tags: youtube-data-api

Im using this url to get video data - 
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=VIDEOID&key=MYKEY&part=snippet&fields=items/id,items/snippet/title,items/snippet/description,items/snippet/thumbnails/high

it was working fine previously. Today I started getting accessNotConfigured error. I checked the dev console and the youtube api is ENABLED. I tried generating a new key but still getting the same error message...

Anyone encountered this issue? Appreciate your help.

Comment: It maybe the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55725403/cant-figure-out-why-i-get-a-403/55790938). Read it through. At the end the issue's initiator says he had to recreate the API project itself.

Comment: I created a new project in google dev console. everything is working now. I still want to know why this happened though...

Comment: I don't know. I never seen any comments on this issue from Google itself either. Maybe you should file a report to [them](https://issuetracker.google.com).